# Why should this be an increasing sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

> Define a sequence $[x_n]_n $ by $x_n = \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3}...\frac{1}{2n}.$

Is this an increasing or decreasing sequence?

 I did this at first: 
$$x_n = \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3}...\frac{1}{2n}$$
$$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3} + \frac{1}{n+4}...\frac{1}{2n + 2}$$
$$ x_{n+1}-x_n = \frac{1}{2n+2} + \frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1}$$
$$x_{n+1}-x_n = \frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+2}$$ which is always greater than zero. So the sequence is monotonically increasing.
Merely out of curiosity I tried taking the derivative of $x_n$ w.r.t $n$ and the derivative came out to be negative for all real $n$. So the function is decreasing?

I then realised that $x_n$ is not continuous over the set of natural numbers $\mathbb N$ so it was probably incorrect to take the derivative.
However, let's just assume that $n$ was real. Then the graph would be derivable. In that case, shouldn't $x_{n+1}$ be lesser than $x_n$ since $x_{n}$ would be decreasing for all $n \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: How can you compute the derivative with respect to $n$ if the number of terms to be added changes with $n$?

Comment: This is essentially the same flaw as in the (well-known) fake proof that $1 =\frac 1n  + \frac 1n + \cdots + \frac 1n$ converges to zero because each term converges to zero.

Comment: @MartinR Sure, the number of terms does change with n, but the sign of the derivative would be negative irrespective of the number of terms.(Right?)

Comment: Again: $x_n = \frac 1n  + \frac 1n + \cdots + \frac 1n$ ($n$ terms) is constant, although each term decreases with $n$.

Comment: It is true that the first term of $x_{n+1}$ is smaller than the first term of $x_n$; and likewise for the second term and third term and so on. But $x_{n+1}$ has an extra term.  For example: $x_2=\frac13+\frac14$ and $x_3=\frac14+\frac15+\frac16$. The excess of $\frac16$ more than makes up for the loss in the first two terms.

Comment: @paw88789 Thanks, I get that. But my question essentially is this: What I've done with derivatives seems to be correct. Then why doesn't the math work out?

Comment: @MartinR Fair enough. But how do I get out of this paradox? Calculus isn't wrong, so what is? There has to be a flaw in my method. Please help me find it.

Comment: @AmbicaGovind The math does work out. The first $n$ terms of $x_{n+1}$ are term-by-term less than the $n$ terms of $x_n$ (that's the decreasing you expect based on the derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$). But there is one extra term in $x_{n+1}$, which is greater than the total amount of decrease in the first $n$ terms. So the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is indeed increasing.

Comment: @paw88789 By math, I meant the calculus. Should've been more specific.